# get last character in a string

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone

I am new to developing windows phone apps. Now I am creating a text messenger app with T9 keyboard, I already made design like the buttons. Now what I want is how can I get the last character in a string? Example the string is "clyde", how can I get the char 'e' from that String?
I am using Visual Basic as language.

UPDATE: Got it working now, I used this code:

```
string s = "clyde";
char e = s(s.Length-1);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure about which language are you using, but in C# it is done like

```
string s = "clyde";
char e = s[s.Length-1];
```

and it is very similar in every language.

Comment: this one works, thanks so much. but the bracket has an error so I changed the brackets to parenthesis.

Comment: The brackets are correct for C#, parenthesis is for Visual Basic

Answer (score 9):

C#:

```
string clyde = "clyde"; 
char last = clyde[clyde.Length - 1];
```

VB.NET

```
Dim clyde as String = "clyde"
Dim last as Char = clyde(clyde.Length - 1)
```

Comment: the vb.net example is not vb.net

Comment: Dim last As Char = clyde.Last

Answer (score 6):

I would do this with linq :-

```
   string clyde = "Clyde";
   char lastChar = clyde.Last();
```

Just my preference.

Comment: That's a very inefficient way of doing it. Also, no point casting a char to a string.

Comment: For future reference, can you explain how using LINQ is inefficient. Just so that I have my head round it, As I'm not that experienced.

Comment: The Enumerable.Last is only optimized for a IList/ICollection<T> type, where as string just implements a [] overload. As you can see on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx it doesn't implement neither IList<T> or ICollection<T>, and as such the IEnumerable optimization won't work. As such it'll iterate over all items in the collection (all characters in the string), and pick the last. It's a O(n) operation instead of O(1).

Answer (score 3):

C#:

```
String string = "string";
Char lastLetter = string[string.Length - 1];
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim sInput As String  = "sInput"
Dim lastLetter As Char = ChrW(sInput.Length - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

F#:

```
"input" |> Seq.last             //val it : char = 't'
"input" |> Seq.last |> string   //val it : string = "t"
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim s As String = "Clyde"

s = Mid(StrReverse(s), 1, 1)

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
String.First
```

String.last

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).